# ANy software for auto backup of ubuntu system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup-restoration

I am using ubuntu 10.04. Now the ubuntu is performing as i want. Is there any thing like system restore in ubuntu.

SO that if i upgrade the ubuntu softwares  and it stops working and i can restore the system to previous state.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use SBackup for example, which is available by the package manager.

`sudo apt-get install sbackup`

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem) describes good alternatives to backup your system too, like using a versioned file system.

Comment: thanks for that , now i have my drives and shares mounted on /media . Should i include that as well or not. IF i restore that backup will anything happen to data in mounted drives

Comment: How can i backup all root folders , rather than selecting individual folder, is there any harm in selecting root folder

Comment: if you want to back up your whole system, selecting `/` would be the way to go.

there are lots of directories that don't need to be regularly backed up, depending on what you wish to retain... you mentioned your media, you may want to make less frequent backups of that, simply for size and the lack of changes over time.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea to backup `/` as a directory. The system will not allow you to restore it as a copy/paste (which is basically what standard backup manager do).
May be you should look at partition cloning systems, or just select data directories.

Answer (score 0):

if you have good store then you can using remastersys you take running snapshot it will .iso format